# How to repeat ajax call until success

Tags: jquery

When the button "getproduct" is clicked, the ajax call get the product or the 404 code if the product is not avaible.

I want the function getMyJson being call again every 5 seconds until the product is returned.

Any ideas ?

```
$(function () {
    $("#getproduct").click(function getMyJson() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "Product/GetProduct",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                //alert("succes");
                $("#name").html(data.Name);
                $("#price").html(data.Price);
            },
            error: function () {
                //alert("fail");
                //callback getMyJson here in 5 seconds
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use `setTimeout` in `error` callback function

```
$(function () {
    function getMyJson() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "Product/GetProduct",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                //alert("succes");
                $("#name").html(data.Name);
                $("#price").html(data.Price);
            },
            error: function () {
                //alert("fail");
                //callback getMyJson here in 5 seconds
                setTimeout(function () {
                    getMyJson();
                }, 5000)
            }
        });
    }
    $("#getproduct").click(function () {
        getMyJson();
    });
});
```