# Retry ajax call until successful

Tags: javascript

I have an Ajax call that I would like to retry when failing, based on this current code :

```
$.ajax({
        url: "<%= my_ruby_on_rails_controller_url_here %>",
        datatype: "json",
        type: "GET",
        success: function (json) {
            document.getElementById("factureload" + json.hashed_id).innerHTML = "<a href='" + json.address + "'><img class='pdficonstyling' src='/assets/pdf4.svg' alt='pdf icon' /> facture_" + json.numfacture + "</a>";
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("fail");

        }
    });
```

I have tried to encapsulate it inside a new function with a callback to this function in `error` (together with `setTimeout`) but it never starts ...

Also There could be concurrent Ajax calls such as this one for different dom elements.

(there is this useful thread but I am so bad in JS I cannot adapt it to my code [How to repeat ajax call until success](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20583302/how-to-repeat-ajax-call-until-success) )

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That link you posted contains the exact answer ... you just need to wrap your code in a function so it can be used recursively:

```
function myAjaxRequest () {
  $.ajax({
    url: "<%= my_ruby_on_rails_controller_url_here %>",
    datatype: "json",
    type: "GET",
    success: function (json) {
      document.getElementById("factureload" + json.hashed_id).innerHTML = "<a href='" + json.address + "'><img class='pdficonstyling' src='/assets/pdf4.svg' alt='pdf icon' /> facture_" + json.numfacture + "</a>";
    },
    error: function () {
      setTimeout(() => {
        myAjaxRequest()
      }, 5000) // if there was an error, wait 5 seconds and re-run the function
    }
  })
}

myAjaxRequest()
```

Comment: thanks @djfdev my IDE shows some warnings with `=>` but I fixed it from the thread I mention. Though one problem : it never starts. When my ajax bit starts with `$.ajax` then I can get an `alert` on fail but when i put into a function it never starts at all (I want it to start when it appears because this Js and ajax bit is triggers by a Rails JS view, then there is no trigger like `onclick` or such ..) (actually this ajax bit is added from another ajax call: user record an invoice number then a dom is populated with a PDF link once the invoice pdf is generated)

Comment: I edited my answer to show this ... but wrapping it in a function creates a function, and doesn't actually execute it. You'll have to actually call the function to make the AJAX call (see the last line)

Comment: Additionally, your editor is probably showing warnings because it supports an older version of JavaScript.

Comment: Answer is correct according to your question. Should be accepted tbh

Comment: Fantastic ! just works perfectly now (yes my IDE probably running some old Js but I can't even tell him what to do with confidence until I know Js a bit better ^^ )

Answer (score 0):

```
function tryUntilSuccess(success) {
   $.ajax({
      url: '<%= my_ruby_on_rails_controller_url_here %>',
      datatype: 'json',
      type: 'GET',
      success: success,
      error: function(err) {
          console.log('Request failed. Retrying...', err)
          tryUntilSuccess(success)
     },
  })
}

tryUntilSuccess(function onSuccess(json) {
    document.getElementById("factureload" + json.hashed_id).innerHTML = "<a href='" + json.address + "'><img class='pdficonstyling' src='/assets/pdf4.svg' alt='pdf icon' /> facture_" + json.numfacture + "</a>";
})
```